# Ping IP Two Times - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip, subprocess, ping

I have one simple question about `subprocess.call`.

I'm trying to ping some IP addresses, and ping instruction is pinging it 4 times.

But I want to ping every address 2 times. Can I add any value like count =  to `subprocess.call?

I was checking documentation about that, and have found nothing helping me to resolve this, or maybe is there any other instruction to use.

Or do I have to make a method for this? And add count variable?

This is the code:

```
import subprocess
#import time

for ping in range (30,36):
    ipek = "192.168.0." + str(ping)
    subprocess.call(["ping", ipek])
```

Comment: Yes, paste code – obviously, that'll help. Also, you're looking at the wrong end: `subprocess` has nothing to do with what `ping` does. You need to look at the documentation of `ping`, not at that of `subprocess.call`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
import subprocess #import subprocess

for ping in range(30, 36): #all ip's ending in 30 to 36
    ipek = "192.168.0." + str(ping) #set ip string
    subprocess.call(["ping", ipek, "-n", "2"]) #ping
```

Comment: i was doing tha same thing Brendan but i got something like that

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ip.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["ping", ipek, "-n", count]) #ping
  File "C:\---Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\---Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__

Comment: Is that not what you want?

Comment: That does it twice

Comment: Can you run that exact code and only that code? Are you on windows?

Comment: i think subproces..call cant take argument count,
yes im on windows 10

Comment: pycharm, + python 3.6.2

Comment: Im trying Brendan, and i have some issues, and cant execute code

Comment: If that does not work then open a command prompt  and type `python C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/untitled2/ip.py`

Comment: It's working now Brendan :) how can i thank You for that?

Comment: Mark my answer as correct by click the grey check mark and upvoting it!

Comment: thankYou i will check that always :) and now im going to search any code for making my code better :)